# Perguntas com numero de visita acima de 99 mil quebram layout da página inicial

Tags: bug, status-aceito, layout

Navegando na home encontrei a seguinte pergunta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Consegui reproduzir no Chrome e no Firefox.

Por ser uma pergunta com muitas visitas, acredito que acabou quebrando a linha pelo número de caracteres extra.

Caso ajude, a parte do *markup* que quebrou.

```
<div class="question-summary narrow" id="question-summary-6441">
<div onclick="window.location.href='/questions/6441/qual-%c3%a9-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join'" class="cp">
    <div class="votes">
        <div class="mini-counts"><span title="190 votos">190</span></div>
        <div>votos</div>
    </div>
    <div class="status answered-accepted" title="uma das respostas foi aceita como resposta correta">
        <div class="mini-counts"><span title="5 respostas">5</span></div>
        <div>respostas</div>
    </div>
    <div class="views">
        <div class="mini-counts supernova"><span title="118494 visitas">118mil</span></div>
        <div class="supernova">visitas</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="summary">

    <h3><a href="/questions/6441/qual-%c3%a9-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join" class="question-hyperlink">Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN?</a></h3>
    <div class="tags t-sql t-join">
        <a href="/questions/tagged/sql" class="post-tag" title="mostrar perguntas com a tag 'sql'" rel="tag">sql</a> <a href="/questions/tagged/join" class="post-tag" title="mostrar perguntas com a tag 'join'" rel="tag">join</a> 
    </div>
    <div class="started">
        <a href="/questions/6441/qual-%c3%a9-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join/?lastactivity" class="started-link">respondidas <span title="2017-09-29 11:08:02Z" class="relativetime">45 minutos atrás</span></a>
        <a href="/users/92848/maiza-rocha">Maiza Rocha</a> <span class="reputation-score" title="pontos de reputação " dir="ltr">1</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Aqui também....

Comment: Qual pergunta? Tem link?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%c3%a9-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join a pergunta é essa, mas não importa muito pois é preciso encontrá-la em alguma listagem

Comment: Caros, este problema não foi resolvido, como pode ser visto neste print tirado hoje(24/09/2018)  após [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32936/28595) receber uma resposta: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ej6T6.jpg

Comment: @Articuno Uma pena que não dá para colocar recompensa em perguntas do meta.

Answer (score 2):

Consegui simular, isso ocorre quando o "campo" de visitas chega a 100.000 ou maior, nisso o valor é convertido em 100mil, ainda sim 6 digitos são o suficiente para quebrar o layout, a parte do HTML relevante é esta:

```
<div class="mini-counts hot"><span title="00000 visitas">100mil</span></div>
```

Uma possível solução seria no seletor existente `.narrow .cp` adicionar max-width e nowrap, deve ficar assim:

```
.narrow .cp {
    white-space: nowrap;
    max-width: 178px;
    vertical-align: top;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Vejam um exemplo em tempo de execução feito pelo console do Opera/Chrome:

[image: fixando bug]

Coloquei 10000mil (10.000.000) só de exemplo, claro que talvez no um milhão exista alguma outra abreviatura, mas o teste é apenas para ver o efeito, fica um pouco vazado, mas já ajuda.